# Django security risk url parameters

Tags: django

I am trying to find a way to prevent users changing url parameters and messing around with the system. I know you can restrict users to only have access to the right content, but still if the url is

```
www.site.com/something/10
```

And I change 10 to 9 in the address bar,  i can access something the work flow is not designed to give access to. I can restrict the person not to view 9, but it still provide the opportunity to mess around with something, I might have overlooked.

By using POST method and hiding the parameters it will cause problems as django is not designed to handle many forms in one view.

Is there a way to let django rather display

```
www.site.com/something/<Encrypted> or <Not recognisable so I can mess around>
```

There must be some way of limiting users only to access, whatever the links provide on the current page, instead of a clever user trying to cause harm.

Comment: What about after getting the number from URL check if this user authorized to make anything with it let's say if the number was profile number check if the profile belong to this user before do anything with it

Comment: You can use any value you like as a URL parameter; the main issues are that it needs to be unique, and you will need to store it in the model so it can be used as a query. One good candidate for this is a UUID.

Comment: You can't skip validating your input by encrypting it -- i.e. after decrypting you _still_ have to validate that the current user is allowed to perform the requested action (both permission wise and context wise).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django-encrypted-id where you can do something like

```
In [12]: e = ekey(Something.objects.first()) # Call this wherever you render a url

In [13]: e
Out[13]: 'bxuZXwM4NdgGauVWR-ueUA'

In [14]: get_object_or_404(Something, e) # Call this wherever you receive a request
Out[14]: <Something: thingy>
```

https://github.com/amitu/django-encrypted-id

However I would recommend in addition writing tests to ensure you haven't overlooked anything, and writing permission classes for all your views. Since people could still send urls or be connected on a shared network via http and accidentally give others access to things they are not supposed to have access if this were the only security measure.